# Drupal 7 : difference between node insertion / node update

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, nodes, updates, insertion

I've created a module to get server informations.
So i've created a specific content type.To collect all the data one field is required the hostname.

I use the function `hook_node_presave()` to add information such as CPU, RAM, etc in my node. So when I create a new node, I specify manually the name and drupal call the function `hook_node_presave()` which automatically insert the other information in my node.

I have also setted a cron to update every node informations periodically. To do this I use `hook_cron()`. I manage to load every node thanks to `node_load()`, to update them, but when I want to save them using `node_save()` Drupal call logically `hook_node_presave()`... But don't want this to happen : because this function update once more the information !

How can I differenciate **new node** and **updated node** in `hook_node_presave()`?
Otherwhise which function can I call to avoid this problem ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check the `is_new` member on the node object or for the existence of a `nid`:

```
function MYMODULE_node_presave($node) {
  if ($node->is_new) {
    // ...
  }
 
  // Equivalent to
  if (empty($node->nid)) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Per the [`user_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_save/7) docs:

> **Parameters**
>
> $node: The $node object to be saved. If $node->nid is omitted (or $node->is_new is TRUE), a new node will be added.